# Custom Post Login class in Liferay is not invoked

Tags: java, redirect, liferay-6

I'm a newbie in Liferay and I'm creating a hook to authenticate using a expando column instead of an email address.
My authentication class works fine, but one problem still remains:

After a successful authentication, I must redirect the page to the user's public or private page (any of theese is enough for me)
I followed the common of instructions for this on any forum on Internet:

1. Create a class that extends com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action and do the logic there. In my case, my class is named CustomPostLoginAction
2. Modify portal.properties adding the entries

   `login.events.post=com.liferay.sample.hook.action.CustomPostLoginAction`
   `auth.forward.by.last.path=true`
   `default.landing.page.path=/web/guest/home`
3. Redeploy and "voilá"

When I reboot my web server, everything is fine, but when I run my hook using any browser, once I get successfully authenticated, it stills showing me the default login error messages. When I check my console, I found that my action class is never called and no special action is executed after my authentication class. So I have the following questions:

- Where can I found an example to class to be used as a value for the property "auth.pipeline.post" if needed?
- On the method `authenticateByEmailAddress` on my authentication class, the last argument is a `java.util.Map` containing parameters like "doActionAfterLogin", "redirect", "structsAction", etc. Do I get something if I assign values to those keys on that map? If yes, where can I found an example of valid values to assign to each one of them?
- Do I have to change something in my custom login page? (it works, but still I have to ask this)
- Is it necessary to work with the class `DefaultLandingPageAction`? If yes, how can I do it? Because I have only the portal's bytecodes (.class)
- And most important: What am I doing wrong?

For the record:

I'm using Liferay 6.1 bundle with Tomcat 7 and SDK included with Liferay's default database.
If any of you need to watch any of my source code and/or properties files, just let me know and I will publish them.

Thanks in advance to all of you.

Comment: I tried to modify the `Map<String, String[]>` used as the last argument of the `authenticateByEmailAddress` method of my Authentication class and i found out that it's useless, so the second question is answered.

Comment: Also, i have an additional problem: Some forums told me that on the key `login.events.post` in my `portal.properties` file i have to prepend the class `com.liferay.portal.events.LoginPostAction` (and obviously put a comma between that class and my post login class). If i do this, when i redeploy my hook, Tomcat throws a `com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering hook` (...) `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.events.LoginPostAction`. (continue on next comment)

Comment: (following the last comment) But `LoginPostAction` is a Liferay defined class and i can create any instance of `LoginPostAction` on any of my classes. What can i do to solve this?

Comment: Another question: Is it good idea to use ext-plugins instead of hook to solve the main problem? If yes, where can i find a example of an ext-plugin that overrides a post login event? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment to your original post so I'm gonna have to post an answer to ask you for some additional information (will update my answer accordingly).

Did you modify `portal.properties` directly or did you create a new `portal.properties` inside your hook?

Once you extended `com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action`, did you *override* the `run` method?